# How to get a custom field in theme customizer to live update the element in preview window?

Tags: theme-customizer

I created a custom field for theme customizer, and all works fine to display the field, save the value to the DB and retrievable via `get_theme_mod()`, but it does not live update in the preview window. I have to reload the page to see the change.

The preview does refresh on each change of the fields and the `Publish` button is activated, but now I need the change to be detected and processed by the `wp.customize` javascript API.

**The result from the custom field coding**

[image: image of the custom field result]

Based on multiple searches, I have tried the following methods without success. Note this is just part of the code. The retrieved value uses the respective ID for each field setting which are `head1font` and `head1size` but the below is just of one. The code shows the two methods tried, but note that both are not used at the same time.

```php
add_action('customize_controls_print_scripts', function() 
{
  echo'
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
     // setting.bind method
      wp.customize("head1font", function(setting) {
        setting.bind(function(value) {
            $("h1.pagetitle").css("font-family",value);
        });
      });

    // other method tried value.bind
      wp.customize("head1font", function(value) {
        value.bind(function(newval) {
            $("h1.pagetitle").css("font-family",newval);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
 ';
});
```

The console note does not seem applicable. The following is the notice when a change action occur.

```
Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.
```

I am now at a loss for a solution so I am seeking tips to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined a solution. The `transport` type had to be changed from default `refresh` to `postMessage` to use the custom JS instruction.

```php
add_action('customize_register', function($mgr) 
{
  //load the custom field class file
  include_once LIBPATH.'/classTplFormat.php';

  // moved the JS into a file and loaded via enqueue
  // ASSETURL is a constant that holds theurl to the assets folder
  add_action('customize_preview_init', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script('tpl-customizer', ASSETURL.'/tpl-customizer.js',[],'',true);
  });

  // the fields are in the custom class and too much to post but it follows
  // similar method as the core customizer eg: add_panel(), add_section(), add_setting()
  $mgr->add_control(new TplFormat($mgr, 'tplformat',[]));
  //set the transport method to the specific field
  $mgr->get_setting('head1font')->transport = 'postMessage';
});
```

**JS**

```js
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    wp.customize("head1font", function(value) {
        value.bind(function(value) {
            $("h1.pagetitle").css("font-family",value);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```